# How to check angle between raycast and surface?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know how to check angle between raycas(Vector3.Angle(hit.normal, -transform.forward)), but my problem is that it always returns the smaller angle(i know it's mathematically correct, it's just not what i want). I'm using it to determine in which side should my car turn. It's hard to explain so I will use picture:
[image: raycast]
This two raycasts would both return same angle, and I want one to bo 45* and the other -45*. Actually I don't need exact value, 1 and -1 would be good as well(I need to know only the side, not the exact angle).

Comment: it's incredibly hard to do this.  I would just find another way. for example, trivially check if one is to the "left" (or "west" - or whatever) - which is easy.

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more?The problem is that this wall can be rotated in any direction so I suppose this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if this will help you with your problem, but looking at your example it might work for you:

[image: pic]

When you look at the modified picture, I have added the vector `U` and have named the red vectors, where  `L` (and `R`) and pointing from the wall (the hit point, indicated by the vertical lines) towards the rectangle. The vector `U` is a fixed direction vector associated with your wall (so it does not change at runtime).

Now taking `L` and `U` (or `R` and `U`) you can determine whether the ray origin lies *behind* or *in front of* the hit point by using the **dot product**.

In this example, that yields:
`Vector3.Dot(L, U) < 0` 
`Vector3.Dot(R, U) > 0`

You could then use this information to determine a sign for your angles.

Comment: Great idea, but I don't really know how to associate some vector wit direction of my walls. Do you know how to do it or is it just mathematical solution?

Comment: it can be pretty easy when you align your wall model with its game obejcts local axis that is pointing right (for example). using transform.right will then give the world space projection of the local (eventually rotated) axis pointing right. use this as your U vector

Comment: Thank you! That solves my problem. In case anyone else would want to use that you have to use Vector3.Dot, not Mathf.Dot.

Comment: glad I could help, ah sorry didn't look that up and thought it was in Mathf :) I will correct my answer